# Accessing state of Beacon Chain in a solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, beacon-chain

I'm working on a Solidity smart contract and need to access info about the state of the Beacon Chain. For example, I would like to get a list of current validators, their balances,slashings, previous and current epoch attestations etc. Is it possible to achieve this directly from within a Solidity smart contract, and if so, how can I go about it?

I found the [special variables and functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) of solidity, but they don't provide the info I need.

I am aware that I can use a blockchain explorer like etherscan or beaconcha.in for this, but I wonder if doing it on-chain is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity smart contracts can only access the Ethereum Virtual Machine state. The beacon chain (consensus layer) is not part of the EVM chain (execution layer).

Some information might be available from [Beacon chain deposit smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa).

Information that is not available in any of the deployed smart contracts is not possible to read without the use of external oracles that would submit the information to the blockchain first.